# Trouble installing wildcard SSL cert on MS server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl

I've been give a set of files for a wildcard certificate from a client.  This set of files includes a .pem, .crt, .pfx, and a ca-bundle file.

If i try to import the pfx, i get prompted for a password, however the client is unable to give me a password.

I then used openssl to extract a .cer file from the pfx, however when i create a certificate with that, it appears in the certificate manager, but disappears after refresh.  My research leads me to believe this happens when the .cer is missing a private key.

I'm running out of things to try, anybody got an idea?

Comment: `the client is unable to give me a password`.  Get the password.

Comment: Easier said than done, he says he doesnt have one and that others have gotten this to work by performing some kind of conversion, yet he doesnt know the details of that process either.

Comment: You are asking how to extract a password-protected private key from a pfx without having the password. If you cannot get the password, get another certificate pfx. with a password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is how i did it using openssl:

openssl pkcs12 -export -out out.pfx -inkey server_key.pem -in crtname.crt

I was then able to import the certificate into the certificate manager and also create a ssl certificate in IIS.